# Чи українське сленгове «матьорий» = калька з російського "матёрый"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, запозичені-слова, сленг

Привіт, лінгістичне товариство.
Отож, серед молоді досить поширене є слово «[матьорий](https://www.slangzone.net/word/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)», яке означає щось прикольне, класне, хороше, рідше, таке, що викликає повагу або захоплення.

В московитській мові це слово означає або досвідчену людину, або зрілого звіра. Натомість, я не знайшов щоб це слово вживалося б у тому ж значенні як і в українському сленгу (швидкий пошук по твітерах/фейсбуках і форумах різних).

З прямих перекладів я знайшов лише «зугарний», яке теж використовується, щоб підкреслити чийсь досвід або вміння в певній галузі.

Чи це наслідок якихось нез'ясованих лінгвістичних кочувань цього слова?
Чи безпечно казати, що слово «матьорий» не є калькою з російської, якщо має інше значення?

Comment: а і бтв, зугарний частіше всього використовується як дієприкметник, дієприкметник від слова матьорий радше не вдасться створити.

Answer (score 2):

Цікаве запитання. Перші речі — спочатку.

Слово має два правописи московською: *матеро́й* або *матё́рый*.

Тлумачний словник Фасмера [ось що пише](https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/%D0%BC/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9) про це слово. Цитата (переклад мій):

> *матеро́й матёрый*, **[укр](https://#). *ма́терий*** «немолодий», [блр.](https://#) мато́рны, [ст.-слов.](https://#) *матерьство πρεσβεῖον, заматорѣвъ, заматерѣвъ προβεβηκώς*, [цслов.](https://#) *матеръ, маторъ* «старий», [болг.](https://#) *ма́тор* «міцний, здоровий, зрілый, старий», [сербохорв.](https://#) *ма̏тор* «старий», словен. *matȯ́r* «пристаркуватий», [чес.](https://#) *matorný* «серйозний, суворий», [польск.](https://#) *zаmаtоrzаłу, zamotrzały* «затверділий»
> Швидше за все, це [праслов.](https://#) похідне від *мати*, аналогічно до [лат.](https://#) *māteria, māteriēs* «будівельний ліс, матерія»; див. Траутман, ВSW 171; Бернекер 2, 25; Вальде-Гофм. 2, 50 та сл[овники].
> Інші вважають спорідненим до [лат.](https://#) *mātūrus* «зрелый», *mānе* «вранці» (Мейе, ét. 407; Маценауер, LF 10, 64), [вірм.](https://#) *mairi* «будівельний ліс, дерево» (Леві, KZ 40, 562; Бернекер 2, 25). Спорідненість із [грец.](https://#) *μάτις ̇ μέγας* (Гесихий), [дав.-ірл.](https://#) *maith* «хороший» (Петерссон, Verm. Beitr. 128) не доведене. Запозичення з [лат.](https://#) *mātūrus* є неприйнятним, всупереч Романському (JIRSpr. 15, 120; див. Бернекер, там само). Випадковим є співзвучність з [тюрк.](https://#) словами «спритний, хоробрий»; [тат.](https://#) *matur, matyr*, [чув.](https://#) *mоdог* і т. ін. (див. Рясянен, TschL. 154 и сл.; Паасонен, FUF 2, 126) [Махек (ZfslPh, 23, 1954, стор. 117) на підставі [мор. діал.](https://#) *zmateřelé obilí* «зерно, що згнило» передбачає спорідненість з [нім.](https://#) *modern* «гнилий, тухлий». — Т.]

Як бачимо, сам Фасмер дає український еквівалент.

Окрім того, заслуговує на увагу згаданий у цій же статті білоруський варіант *мато́рны*, цілком слушно запропонувати слово ***моторний***. Саме це слово використовується у першому рядку «Енеїди»:

> Еней був парубок моторний

З практичної точки зору, зауважив наступне:

- йдеться про молодіжний жаргон, а це, без перебільшення, галузь мови, що найбільш динамічно розвивається.
- слово *матьорий* у цьому жаргоні має непряме значення, адже не обов'язково мається на увазі статево-зрілий самець у розквіті своїх років, сили, спритності тощо.

Тому вважаю за можливе також використовувати будь-який варіант на розсуд читача, але також бути готовим сприйняти якийсь інший варіант, який читач може почути від оточуючих.

---

#### Висновки

Таким чином,

1. ***Моторний*** є словниковим і широко відомим у літературі.
2. суто з лінгвістичної точки зору, слово ***ма́терий*** можна вважати усталеним (окрім зауваження, що Макс Фасмер таки вів словник іноземної мови).
3. В контексті молодіжного жаргону, можна експериментувати з будь-якими варіантами.

Answer (score 0):

В англійській маємо *seasoned* теж зі значенням *досвідчений*.

Ось, що r2u дає для *матёрый*:

> Матеро́й –
>
> 1. *(большой)* матерни́й, здоро́вий, *(высокий)* висо́кий, *(дебелый)* дебе́лий, *(крепкий)* креме́зни́й.
>    • -рой *человек* – креме́зна́ (дебе́ла) люди́на, креме́зний (дебе́лий) чолові́к, кремезня́к, моца́к (-ка́).
>    • -ро́й *бык, заяц* – здоро́вий (дебе́лий) буга́й (-гая́), бик (-ка́), віл (р. вола́), здоро́вий за́єць (р. за́йця). [Ва́жко ру́шили з мі́сця дебе́лі воли́ (Основа)].
>    • -ро́й *улей, рой, см.* Ма́точный 2.
>    • -ро́й *дуб* – стари́й висо́кий дуб (-ба).
>    • -ро́й *лес* – товстолі́с (-су). -ра́я *утка, зоол.* Anas crecca, *см.* Кря́ква;
> 2. *(взрослый)* доро́слий, ді́йшлий, дохожа́лий, *(возмужалый)* змужні́лий.
>    • -рые *годы* – му́жні літа́, му́жній вік (-ку);
> 3. -ра́я *земля, см.* Матери́к 1 и 3;
> 4. -ра́я (сщ.) *реки, см.* Материк 5.

Тобто це скоріше пряме запозичення з російської ніж калька.

Comment: питання було саме про сленгове значення, а не таке, як у московитській.